# Query in Django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to query inside a django template, but i am just not sure how to correctly phrase the query, i have two models 1-category 2-items and i am trying to get all the items of a specific category from it's ID `{% for item in Category.objects.get(id=${this.id}).items.all%}{{item.name}}{%endfor%}`

here is the complete template:

```
<div class="inventory-content">
    <div class='category'>
        <div>Categories</div>
        <div class='category-checkbox'>
            {%for category in items%}
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{category.id}}" name="{{category.name}}" value="{{category.id}}">
            <label for="{{category.name}}"> {{category.name}}</label><br>
            {%endfor%}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='items'></div>
    
</div>    

<script>
    $('.category-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          // Add the element to the div with an id identifier
          $('.items').append(`<div id="item_${this.id}">{% for item in Category.objects.get(id=${this.id}).items.all%}{{item.name}}{%endfor%}</div>`);
        } else {
          // Remove the element from the div targeted by the id identifier
          $(`#item_${this.id}`).remove();
        }
      });
</script>
```

models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    vessel = models.ForeignKey(Vessel,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='category')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    part_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    ROB = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category,related_name='items',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py:

```
def index(request,pk):
    vessel_id = Vessel.objects.get(id=pk)
    categories = vessel_id.category.all()
    category = Category.objects.all()
    item = categories.prefetch_related(
        'items')
    context ={"vessel_id":vessel_id,'items':item,"category":category}
    return render(request,'inventory.html',context)
```

also i have been told it's bad practice to write query inside the template, so if you can guide me what better way could i have achieved this ?which is querying for all items in a specific category when checked

Comment: Can you show `views` please?

Comment: i have edited and included my views @NixonSparrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `vessel_id` you have `Vessel` object, not its `id`. Be careful with that.
You should definitely get what you need in your `views`. You already know, how to pass and use `context`. Even for `scripts`, but it might be little more tricky. You can try:

```
script_insider = ''.join([item.name for item in Category.objects.get(id=id_you_want).items.all()])
```

It should sum your `Items` names to that: 'name_1name_2name_3'. You can use ' ' instead of '', then whitespace will separate the names: 'name_1 name_2 name_3'.

In templates you cannot use freely the code. You will mostly use `for` loops and `if` conditionings. You can also read about [Custom Tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) that can sometimes be more precise with template values.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to call methods with arguments in Django templates, so there is no way you can write a query inside template.

The only right way is to query inside a view and then pass the ResultSet to context inside `render()` function.

Comment: Thank you, i defiantly have to fix things up in the view rather than the template